# Destroying users as an admin in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use Devise to delete users. I have a list of users each with their email and a 'delete' link next to them, only visible to me, the administrator. I want to be able to simply click the delete link to remove the user forever. The following code deletes me, the administrator!

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_registration_path, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

I would think you need to pass the :id of the user you want to delete to some kind of 'destroy_user' method:

```
@user.find(params[:id]).destroy_user
```

But how do you do this when you have to submit a DELETE request to the user_registration_path??

------ EDIT --------

OK, I've added this method to my users controller:

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

So, I need to tell the users controller to invoke the destroy method when it receives a DELETE request. How do you do this in routes.rb? Currently I have:

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show',    :as => :user
match '/all_users', :to => 'users#index',   :as => :all_users
```

I need something like:

```
match 'delete_user', :to => 'users#destroy', :as => :destroy_user, :method => :delete
```

but this doesn't work. And what should go in the link?:

```
<%= link_to "delete", destroy_user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

To put it another way, what should you put in the routes.rb file in order to distinguish between different request types (GET, DELETE etc) to the same url?

Comment: This totally pointed me in the right direction - Be sure that you order the lines correctly in the Routes.rb file. I put the match lines below the devise_for :users line and everything runs great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise doesn't provide an action to delete another user, only to delete the currently logged in user.  You'd have to create your own action in one of your controllers (most likely, whichever controller has the action to display all the users) to handle deleting a user other than the currently logged in one.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but struggling (see edit). I don't know a) what url to use in the routes file: 'match [url], :to => users#destroy', and b) how to tell it to hit users#destroy only when this mystery url receives a DELETE request.

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to recreate the routes implemented by the command 'resources :users' in the routes file, but I don't want to use 'resources :users, :only => [:destroy] if I can help it.

Answer (score 4):

Replace 'user' by the actual user that you want to destroy, ex: if you're printing out the email as user.email, then plugin the user there et voilà

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_registration_path(user), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

Comment: You'll get a `401 Unauthorized` if you aren't signed in as that user.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Simply needed to add the :via argument in routes:

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show',    :as => :user,         :via => :get
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#destroy', :as => :destroy_user, :via => :delete
```