# How to prevent automatic signing-out in devise when destroying a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have a application whereby a user can destroy other users attached to the same account.

I use Devise for authentication and want to be able to allow a user to destroy other users. I have this bit working but I'm struggling to prevent devise from logging me out even though I'm deleting another user.

I have created my own registrations_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def edit
    ...
    super
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
    redirect_to :root
  end

end
```

And the link that destroys each one of my users looks like this:

`<%= link_to "Yes", registration_path(@user), :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "button" %>`

However, each time I click this link it logs me out even though it is another user I am deleting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are not destroying the user logged in? Looks to me that way. Also, you don't need to have all those actions with the super line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem I solved this via this post. Basically devise can't delete any other user apart from the current one. You need to add a destroy action to destroy users to your other controller that is displaying the current view:

[Destroying users as an admin in Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170518/destroying-users-as-an-admin-in-devise)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same exact issue and realized it wasn't Devise that was the problem. Add this to your layout:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Rails expects that you have the CSRF authentication code with each response.  Rails will just ignore a GET request without one, but if you don't include it in a POST/PUT/DELETE request it will silently kill the current session, which logs you out.

When using the `form_for` helper the CSRF code is automatically included.  However, the Rails javascript AJAX helper (the one that handles remote links) looks for the CSRF meta tag so it can attach the code to the request.

Comment: Carbo, thanks but it I already have this in the header.

For anyone else coming across this post solved my problems. Basically devise can't delete any other user apart from the current user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170518/destroying-users-as-an-admin-in-devise